# Javascript Array Parent-Children Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-select2

I am trying to load a Javascript array onto Select2 (jQuery replacement for checkboxes) as follows:

```
$('select').select2({
  data: [
    {
      id: 'value',
      text: 'Text to display'
    },
    // ... more data objects ...
  ]
});
```

Here's the reference: https://select2.github.io/options.html#data

My data structure are as follows:

```
data: 
    [ 
        { 
            id: "Cheek", 
            text: "Cheek",
            children: [{id: "Cheek Palettes", text: "Cheek Palettes"},
                       {id: "Blush", text: "Blush"},
                       {id: "Bronzer", text: "Bronzer"},
                       {id: "Contour", text: "Contour"},
                       {id: "Highlighter", text:"Highlighter"}],
            id: "Eye", 
            text: "Eye",
            children: [{id: "Eye Palettes", text: "Eye Palettes"},
                       {id: "Mascara", text: "Mascara"},
                       {id: "Eyeliner", text: "Eyeliner"},  
        }
    ]
```

The select box I created shows only the last outgroup "Eye" with its child data.
What have I done wrong here?

Comment: It seems like each object of "id,text,children" should be its own entry in the array, no? Right now, it looks like your array contains one object with `id` defined twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is slightly off:

```
data: 
    [ 
        { 
            id: "Cheek", 
            text: "Cheek",
            children: [{id: "Cheek Palettes", text: "Cheek Palettes"},
                   {id: "Blush", text: "Blush"},
                   {id: "Bronzer", text: "Bronzer"},
                   {id: "Contour", text: "Contour"},
                   {id: "Highlighter", text:"Highlighter"}]
        }, // <--- This makes this an array of JSON objects
        { 
            id: "Eye", 
            text: "Eye",
            children: [{id: "Eye Palettes", text: "Eye Palettes"},
                   {id: "Mascara", text: "Mascara"},
                   {id: "Eyeliner", text: "Eyeliner"},
        } // <--- Whereas before, you were replacing the id "Cheek" with "Eye" because JSON only allows one value per key 
    }
]
```